# How to place the JFileChooser on top of the specific Parent Window/Frame

Tags: java, jfilechooser

For my development i use a 3 Monitors. When I open a my Java Application and dragged it to another screen and press a button to display the FileChooser. File Chooser appears on the Main monitor, which is set by the Windows. What is the wrong with this?

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(<parent Comp>);
```

What should i do to make it appear it(File Chooser) on top my Java Application?

Comment: `<parent Comp>` should be your main frame container

Comment: Yes. I set the Main Frame as the <parent comp>. But it didnt work.

Comment: Issue solved. This caused due to Synthetica L&F.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you please clarify how synthetica causes it and what you did to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @Nieke Aerts, I'm pretty sure you have already resolved this problem but for the other visitors, we need to disable "Synthetica.extendedFileChooser.rememberPreferences" property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting the parent in incorrect way

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class MainWindow extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1708404088747322174L;
  private JPanel contentPane;

  /**
   * Create the frame.
   */
  public MainWindow()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    final JButton button = new JButton("Test");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0)
        {
          fileChooser.showOpenDialog(button.getParent());
        }
      });

    contentPane.add(button);
  }

  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(final String[] args)
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
        public void run()
        {
          try
          {
            final MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
            frame.setVisible(true);
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

in this example JFileChooser place on top of parent component